# Implementation of circular enum values

Tags: c++, c++11, enums

What would be the best way to implement an enumeration with circular values, and appropriate functions to transition from a value to another?

For example:

```
enum class Direction {
    NORTH, EAST, SOUTH, WEST
};

constexpr Direction left(Direction d) {
    return (Direction)((std::underlying_type<Directions>::type(d) - 1) % 4);
}
```

However, I feel that this is error prone and generally unreadable. Is there a more proper way to deal with this type of enumerations?

Comment: Spell it out explicitly with a four-case switch statement?  That would be the most readable option.

Comment: What if there were LOTS more values?

Comment: More readable for me if you change `left` to `nextCounterclockwise` (or maybe `nextCCW` in short) :-D

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could always do:

```
enum class Direction {
    NORTH, EAST, SOUTH, WEST, NUMBER_OF_DIRECTIONS
};

constexpr Direction left(Direction d) {
    using ut = std::underlying_type<Direction>::type;
    return (Direction)((ut(d) + ut(Direction::NUMBER_OF_DIRECTIONS)-1)
                       % ut(Direction::NUMBER_OF_DIRECTIONS));
}
```

Usage example / small test:

```
#include <iostream>

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Direction d)
{
    switch(d)
    {
        case Direction::NORTH: return os << "NORTH";
        case Direction::EAST : return os << "EAST";
        case Direction::SOUTH: return os << "SOUTH";
        case Direction::WEST : return os << "WEST";
        default              : return os << "invalid";
    }
}

int main()
{
    Direction d = Direction::NORTH;
    for(int i = 0; i < 2*(int)Direction::NUMBER_OF_DIRECTIONS; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << d << "\n";
        d = left(d);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
NORTH
WEST
SOUTH
EAST
NORTH
WEST
SOUTH
EAST
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9490e0c393a4d520)

Comment: It wouldn't even need the additional element, just do `% (std::underlying_type<Directions>::type(WEST) + 1 )`. But still, it does look like a quick fix doesn't it?

Comment: @Svalorzen : Yup, but `WEST + 1` isn't really human-readable. And what happens if something is added after `WEST`? At least with `NUMBER_OF_DIRECTIONS` its intent is clear.

Comment: @PeterK. Still, you would need to do the whole `underlying_type` to `NUMBER_OF_DIRECTIONS` too, so it would get quite long - and not that readable too.

Comment: Nice trick! It increases the readability of the function, but decreases the readability of the enum.

Comment: @PeterK. How about this implementation? The plus could possibly overflow but I think that's unlikely (integral promotions).